# windows bat file copy issue

Tags: windows, batch-file

The below lines need to copy all the folders from \Reports\Input to
\Deliver\Unidentified\Requests. Input directory contains lot of folders which contains files.

but Below code  is not copying.

If I change dir /b /ad *`) then it is copying only the files from the input folder subdirectories files.

How to change this Please help on this. Thanks advance

Struture:

under Report --> Deliver,Input folder is there

under Input folder -- Response 1,2,3... folder which contains files.

```
CD %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\Reports\Input
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`dir /ad *`)  DO (
                ECHO %%i
                CD "%%i"
                COPY * ..\..\Deliver\Unidentified\Requests
                cd..
)
```

Comment: Have you looked at `xcopy` and `robocopy` yet?

Comment: You have a `Deliver` directory inside `Report`? is the one to copy to?

Comment: yes Deliver directory inside report

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy /S %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\Reports\Input\* %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\Deliver\Unidentified\Request\
```

should work. The `/S` parameter is for recursively copying the files.
You might not need to use a for-loop at all.

Comment: mean while please help me on this to write in bat file- how to write the below code in windows bat file export a=$? echo "RETURN CODE FROM UpgradeR16 = $a"

Comment: I didn't understand the above code.. Sorry pal !! Was the xcopy command successful?

Comment: HTTP and Reports are in same directory

Comment: this is the line previously added CD %AUTOMATEDTESTHTTPDIR%\..\Reports\Input

Comment: Sorry its my mistake then.. But you should have identified it long ago.. Please see the edit in the answer.. I hope Deliver is also in the same directory.. Is the command successful?

Comment: In your bash scriipt , just before xcopy, place this command `setx  INDIR  C:\test\UT_2122\Interface\Test` and  then do `xcopy /S %INDIR%\Reports\Input\* %INDIR%\Deliver\Unidentified\Request\ ` . Please make sure that you are running the cmd as admin. Right Click on cmd.exe and select run as admin

Comment: Did you check `INDIR%\Deliver\Unidentified\Request\ What is int it as present?

Comment: folder is empty files are not there